# Installing facebook sdk for windows 8 app

Tags: facebook, windows-8

Installing facebook sdk for windows 8 app giving error

install-package : Could not install package 'Facebook 6.4.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Are you using latest NuGet package explorer ? Download from http://nuget.org

Comment: yes It is updated version that i am using.

Comment: Try to uninstall any other version of Facebook SDK, if installed as I can't regenerate your problem.

Comment: there is no Facebook SDK installed

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [project page](http://facebooksdk.net) it's the **Facebook SDK for .NET** with Windows 8, Windows Phone, and Web subsets.

I'm assuming you've created either a C++ or JavaScript app - both of which generate the same error for me.  You could perhaps reach out via the [project page](http://facebooksdk.net) to see what options there are for you.